# Import dump into Oracle

Tags: sql, linux, database, oracle, import

I'm trying to import a dmp into my Oracle and I get this error. I've tried many solutions but non of them seems to work for me. I get this error:

```
example@example:~$:imp user/userpass@server:1521/xe file=examplefile.dmp

Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Jul 14 14:46:07 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

IMP-00038: Could not convert to environment character set's handle
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63741/importing-a-different-character-set-export-dump-into-another-db-instance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Set NLS_LANG variable same as your target database variable before export and import.